# In the below program ,what is the difference between the 2 Object Creation which i created and what is the advantage of 2nd one

Tags: java, overriding, object-reference

```
`In the below program ,what is the difference between the 2 Object Creation
      which i created and what is the advantage of 2nd one`
```

1. List item

   ```
   class Overload {

      void sample() {
          System.out.print("Sample ");
       }

      void demo(int a) {
          System.out.print("parent a: " + a);
      }

      void demo(int a, int b) {
          System.out.print("parent a and b: " + a + "," + b);
      }

      double demo(double a) {
          System.out.print("parent double a: " + a);
          return a * a;
      }
   }

   class Overload_1 extends Overload {

      void demo(int a) {
          System.out.print("Child a: " + a);
      }

      void demo(int a, int b) {
          System.out.print(" Child a and b: " + a + "," + b);
      }   

      double demo(double a) {
          System.out.print("Child double a: " + a);
          return a * a;
      }
   }

   class Change_Reference {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
          Overload_1 Obj = new Overload_1(); //What is the of this Object 
          Overload Ob = new Overload_1();//What is the use of this Object 
          double result;
          Obj.demo(10);
          Obj.demo(10, 20);
          result = Obj.demo(5.5);
          System.out.print("O/P : " + result);
          Obj.sample();
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: 1. Could you please fix formatting? 2. Are you asking what is a difference between extending another class and having a class without inheritance?

Comment: My doubt is 1.what is the use of giving child class to the patent class object [Overload Ob = Overload_1();]

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is an "is a" relationship. Let's use dog/animal example:

```
public class Animal {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Dog is an animal, so these are valid:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();
Dog dog = new Dog();
```

So all these calls are valid:

```
animal.run();
dog.run();
dog.bark();
```

However, the type of `animal` is `Animal`, which doesn't have `bark()` method. Dog is an animal, but you refer to it as animal, not as dog, so you don't know that it can bark. For example, `animal` could be a cat instead. This means that this call will give compile error:

```
animal.bark(); // compile-time error, no such method in class Animal
```

So in your example, `Obj` and `Ob` are just references to some objects. Both objects are created in exactly the same way, the only difference is how you refer to them.

I recommend doing some reading about inheritance, you can start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: Thanks :) i get it from your answers